# Android data binding with include tag doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm using android data binding and it is working fine whenever I'm not using the include tag.

If I included a view using the  tag (even it is displaying on the app) but the data binding object doesn't recognize the views of the included layout. These are my layout files.

**internet_unavailable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/internet_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/msg_internet_unavailable"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/internet_button_retry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/internet_margin_top"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/internet_padding_h"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/internet_padding_h"
            android:text="@string/str_retry"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.ncimsl.fragments.ProgressNotesFragment">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/progress_notes_internet"
            layout="@layout/internet_unavailable" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_notes_progressbar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/progress_notes_swiperefreshlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/progress_notes_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

As you can see the progressBar, swipeRefreshLayout and the recyclerView are displaying at the suggestions except the included layout and the views inside it.

[image]

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: it means you want to not show in suggestions

Comment: Are you able to find ..Binding.progressNotesInternet? after resync and rebuild?

Comment: You can check this : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#includes

Comment: @AndroidTeam : It does not show in suggestions. After I typed as  progressNotesInternet, Unable to resolve error.

Answer (score 0):

Performing Rebuild solves the issue for me.

[image: Rebuild Project]

Following is the screenshot from my AndroidStudio after Rebuild:

[image: build works]

My build.gradle:

```
android{
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

My gradle.properties:

`android.databinding.enableV2=true`

Comment: That's strange. Works for me after rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys. I think it was an issue in Android Studio of my PC. I opened the project on another PC and now it's working. Probably I should re-install the Android Studio and give a try.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wanna share my experience to those who still struggle... I had the same problem and it wasn't resolved until turning on [viewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) (in addition to dataBinding) in app's build.gradle. (Android Studio 4.2

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding = true
    viewBinding = true
}
```