# Android Studio(data binding) does not see included layout elements

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-databinding

I have the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940894/android-data-binding-with-include-tag-doesnt-work), but I don’t have enough reputation to ask the author if he could solve it. Can anyone know how to fix this? Android Studio does not see included layout elements. I tried clean project, rebuild project - no helps.

Comment: Try adding `<data> </data>` inside your `<layout> </layout>` tag

Comment: @ZohaibAmir <data> </data> has already been added, everything works for the main layout, only does not see included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to build clean project and after that you should try rebuild because this helped me in the past and if that does not work try re-installing your Android-Studio.

Mostly after re-installing android-studio the project will work properly.

You should check following lines maybe that can help you try adding those lines if you are missing it.

build.gradle:

```
android{
...
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
 }
}
```

gradle.properties:

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Reinstalling Android Studio solved the problem.